# unix command to edit brew formula with vim (or sed)?

Tags: shell, unix, vim, sed, homebrew

When I install boost with homebrew, I change the formula to `layout=system`. The way I do that is:

`brew edit boost`

(in vim)
`:101<enter>wwwcwsystem<esc:wq<enter>`

is there a unix command which can accomplish this series of tasks?

Comment: are you looking for sed?

Comment: don't know homebrew, don't know what you want to do either... is it a general shell/unix/vim question?

Comment: Yes this is general shell/unix/vim. I 'll look into sed... essentially I want to pre-program terminal commands. `brew edit boost` opens vim with the file I want.

Comment: yes it looks like sed would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your homebrew installs to /usr/local, this should do what you need and save a backup as boost.rb.bak

```
sed -i .bak '101s/tagged/system/' /usr/local/Library/Formula/boost.rb
```